# Many generic types in the same list?

Tags: c#

I have a generic class defined like this:

```
public abstract class StationProperty{}

   public class StationProperty<T>
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public T Value { get; set; }
   }
```

I then have a list that looks like this:

```
var props = new List<StationProperty>();
```

So far so good, except when I try to add an item to the list like this:

```
var prop = new StationProperty<bool>(39, true);
// var prop = new StationProperty<int>(39, 100); another example
props.Add(prop);
```

It throws a design time error of: Argument type < bool> is not assignable to parameter type X

My idea is to have a list of values which are strongly typed (not using object), then be able to infer their types using generics later down the road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because a `StationProperty<T>` isn't a `StationProperty`. The only thing they have in common is a name. Perhaps one should derive from the other?

```
public class StationProperty<T>:StationProperty{}
```

Comment: Good spotting, missed it!

Answer (score 1):

`StationProperty` and `StationProperty<T>` are two **independent** classes.

You're creating List of first and inserting there instance of second - that can't be done.